# How to create a sortable table in React? How to access class method from the sorted objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, object

I have an array of objects. i want to access class method inside object function property. How to implement this? please help me. I wrote smth like this:

```
render() {       
  tableTh = [
    {name: i18n.t('ExtendedModalBar.naming'), style:{},  handleSort () {}},
      ...
  ]
  ...
}
```

I am trying to write someth like this:

```
class Table extends Component {

  handleSort() {

  }
  ...

  render() {
  }

}
```

My table headers are formed dynamically:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th style={{ width: "50px" }}>
      <Checkbox
        checked={this.state.selectedAll}
        onChange={() => this.selectAll()}
      />
    </th>
    {tableTh.map((obj, index) => {
      return (
        <th key={index.toString()} style={obj.style} onClick={obj.handleSort}>
          {obj.name}
        </th>
      );
    })}
  </tr>
</thead>
```

I must implement sorting of table columns. If tables are formed statically it is easy to attach onclick to th tag. but if code was written like this, i am stuck.  How to write method in the class that will be accessible from inside property of objects (array of objects) ?   And I need sorting in both directions ascending and descending. My table column should change own sorting direction when I click on its table header. Any answers will be taken into acccount. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to write your code like that? I think the better method would be having `handleSort` in your `Table` class and then passing the object the to it in the onClick listener: `() => this.handleSort(obj)`

Comment: because It is not my code, and  have many tables, my previous "handleSort" function accepts two arguments, columnName and dataToSort. and I attached this function to every column of tables. but in this case, How to pass the specific column with the specific datatosort ?

Comment: check this out https://codesandbox.io/embed/6lmk0q3w5z?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with having the state-changing function on the state itself is that this inherently makes it difficult to manipulate the state.

```
var data = [
  { name: 'a', change: /* ??? */ },
  { name: 'b', change: /* ??? */ },
  { name: 'c', change: /* ??? */ }
]

// How do we write the function ??? to change the order of data?
```

It is much simpler to lift the data-manipulation logic at a higher level (outside of the data itself).

In this case, we would put the data-manipulation logic on the class itself as opposed to within each item.

We can do this by leveraging the [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) in React.

A state is used to hold any (dynamic) presentational (rendered) data for a component. An example of dynamic (changing) presentational data would be a table that sorts its columns.

The reason we want to put presentational data in the state is because React allows us to re-trigger the presentation (by re-rendering) to always show the latest values for our data.

We can achieve this just by changing the data itself and not any presentational logic. This is why React component structure is referred to as [declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming).

Anytime the state is updated, React will call the `render` function to obtain the component structure with the latest state changes and display those on the appropriate medium (in your case the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model))

Here's one way to incorporate state to create a sortable table:

```js
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      sortDirection: "asc", // we start with ascending order by default
      selectedHeaderIndex: 0 // we start by sorting based on the first header (the one in position 0)
    };

    this.ascComparator = (row1, row2) =>
      row1[this.state.selectedHeaderIndex].localeCompare(
        row2[this.state.selectedHeaderIndex]
      );

    this.descComparator = (row1, row2) =>
      row2[this.state.selectedHeaderIndex].localeCompare(
        row1[this.state.selectedHeaderIndex]
      );

    this.flipSortDirection = () =>
      this.state.sortDirection === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
  }

  render() {
    const { headers, rows } = this.props.table;

    const comparator =
      this.state.sortDirection === "asc"
        ? this.ascComparator
        : this.descComparator;

    // sort the rows based on the selected header
    const sortedRows = rows.sort(comparator);

    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          {headers.map((header, i) => (
            <th
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({
                  // if we clicked on the already selected index, we flip the sort direction
                  sortDirection:
                    this.state.selectedHeaderIndex === i
                      ? this.flipSortDirection()
                      : "asc",
                  selectedHeaderIndex: i
                });
              }}
            >
              {header}
            </th>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {sortedRows.map(row => (
            <tr>
              {row.map(cell => (
                <td>{cell}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

const table = {
  headers: ["h1", "h2", "h3"],
  rows: [["a", "9", "+"], ["b", "6", "-"], ["c", "3", "="]]
};

ReactDOM.render(<Table table={table} />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) the code becomes a bit more readable ([click for the CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/oom5p6mm39) since SO doesn't support React 16.8 yet):

```
function Table({ table }) {
  const { headers, rows } = table;

  const [selectedHeaderIndex, setSelectedHeaderIndex] = React.useState(0); // we start by sorting based on the first header (the one in position 0)
  const [sortDirection, setSortDirection] = React.useState("asc"); // we start with ascending order by default

  // determine the sorting comparator based on the sorting direction
  const comparator =
    sortDirection === "asc"
      ? (row1, row2) =>
          row1[selectedHeaderIndex].localeCompare(row2[selectedHeaderIndex])
      : (row1, row2) =>
          row2[selectedHeaderIndex].localeCompare(row1[selectedHeaderIndex]);

  const flipSortDirection = () => (sortDirection === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc");

  // sort the rows based on the selected header
  const sortedRows = rows.sort(comparator);

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        {headers.map((header, i) => (
          <th
            onClick={() => {
              setSelectedHeaderIndex(i);
              setSortDirection(
                selectedHeaderIndex === i ? flipSortDirection() : "asc"
              );
            }}
          >
            {header}
          </th>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {sortedRows.map(row => (
          <tr>
            {row.map(cell => (
              <td>{cell}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

const table = {
  headers: ["h1", "h2", "h3"],
  rows: [["a", "9", "+"], ["b", "6", "-"], ["c", "3", "="]]
};

ReactDOM.render(<Table table={table} />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I need sorting in both directions ascending and descending. How to implement that? my table column should change own sorting direction when I click on its table header.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But Now, it does not sort in both directions. it sorts in turnm which is a bit incorrect

Comment: The reason I wrote it in the constructor is because it's simpler to handle `this` binding using arrow functions. You can definitely move those functions on the class itself but make sure you [bind the context properly](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb).

Comment: I understood everything but I still cannot implement sorting because, in fact, my table data are located outside of the component in another component. And  the table of elements appear in modal window when I click on select items button. how to get those data from another component?    in another component for example: the code is:  selectedItems={this.state.modalItems}   modalItems: this.state.devices.  Another component imports modalBar, in which my tables rendered

Comment: all dataToSort in another component. and it imports and uses  modalWindow component, where my tables exist. How to sort those data how to get them? I must be able to sort table columns inside modal window